# Does static function hide non-static function with the same name?

Tags: c++, c, static

I tried to look this up, but did not find it anywhere. So here's the question:

Static functions in C/C++ can be used to "make them invisible to the outer world". Great, when having two same-named static functions in two different compiled units (.c files), it makes me sure that I call the right one. **But can I also be sure that I call my local static function when there exists a same-named non-static function somewhere in the project or libraries?** That is, does the static function locally hide the non-static one?

Sure I can test it (and I did) but I want to know whether this behaviour has fixed definition in C/C++. Thanks.

**Edit**: Simplified example code which caused unexpected behaviour to me. *The question is about the fix of the problem* (suppose I cannot change the library).

In mylib.c:

```
#include "mylib.h"
int send(void * data, int size);
...
int send(void * data, int size) {
    return send_message(queueA, data, size);
}
void libfunc(void) {
    send(str, strlen(str));
}
```

In mylib.h:

```
// only libfunc is declared here
void libfunc(void);
```

In myprog.c:

```
#include "mylib.h"
int send(void * data, int size);
...
int send(void * data, int size) {
    return send_message(queueB, data, size);
}
void progfunc(void) {
    // expected to send a message to queueB
    // !!! but it was sent to queueA instead !!!
    send(str, strlen(str));
}
```

Compiled `mylib.c` + `further files` -> `mylib.a`

Compiled `myprog.c` -> `myprog.o`

Linked `myprog.o` + `mylib.a` -> `myprog`

Answer (score 4):

You'd get a compilation error because functions have default external linkage, thus the new `static` function would result in a conflict of linkage specifiers.

If the declaration of the non-`static` function isn't visible, the `static` one will be called:

```
void foo();            //external linkage
static void foo() {};  //internal linkage and error
```

Comment: Yes, that's my point - it happened to me recently that in a library source file, there was a local function without the `static` keyword, and in the application I created a function with the same signature. It compiled and even though the library function was not declared in any header, it was executed instead of my local function (which was not static in that time). So, can I rely on hiding the "invisible" non-`static` function by a visible `static` function?

Comment: @yman it couldn't have just "compiled" without being declared. If your local `static` was the only one in that scope, it should have been called. Are you sure the signatures were the same? (exactly the same parameters) Are you sure the function wasn't declared? (a header doesn't have to be included to declare it)

Comment: None of them was `static` originally, sorry if I was unclear. First there was the demonstrated code, which compiled but executed surprisingly, then I fixed it by changing the function `int send(void * data, int size);` in `myprog.c` to `static int send(void * data, int size);`. Now I want to be sure that this behaviour is guaranteed (hence the fix is correct) or it is not defined and I have to find better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It does not hide functions with same name declared in the same scope. However you may not have a function with the same signature declared as having internal and external linkage.